# PC with multiple network cards works as soft switch

Tags: networking

I have pc with multi network cards which is connected by wire to my router (tp link wdr4300) and router to internet. This pc are dns and dhcp server. I want to use this multiple network cards to make soft switch from my pc and connect couple another clients to it and everything should works with the same subnet.

Clients connected to pc should get ip from pc (DNS/DHCP SERVER) then have access to internet through pc to my router and further to internet.

3x Client -> Pc (DNS/DHCP SERVER) -> ROUTER -> INTERNET

My router ip 192.168.1.1, my pc ip 192.168.1.90.

I make bridge from ports on this pc. When i connect another client to it i get ip but this pc doesnt see gateway 192.168.77.1 so probably there is something with routing.

Please help I don't know how to fix it.

[Network topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEPsz.png)

Comment: Are you aware that you can purchase 5-port gigabit switches for less than $20 nowadays?

Comment: Sorry, voted to close because you have not provided sufficient information - like OS.  Under Linux you can use brctl to bridge 2 or more interfaces into a virtual switch.